Snakemake wildcard constraint using negative lookbehind or lookahead
I'm building a snakemake pipeline to align some NGS data, and some of the samples are single end and others are paired end, which require slightly different analyses. My solution was to declare a sample_sp wildcard to use for rules that are specific to a certain type of data. I want this wildcard to not end with _pe, as that is how I am marking files to be used in paired-end experiments.
I saw these answers give solutions using negative lookahead or lookbehind regexes, but snakemake doesn't seem to match the wildcard using these regexes to any of my data files.
Is there any way to get snakemake to use negative lookahead/lookbehind? Or is there another way I can define a wildcard constraint to not end with a certain string?

I've written multiple pipelines that handle paired-end/single-end data using Snakemake and never needed to use lookahead/lookbehind in the regexes. In fact, I'm struggling to even think of an example that would allow me to try that out.
So I think you may have an XY problem here, and there will a better solution to your more general need. If you can share that part of your workflow I'm happy to take a look.

Please do! https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/22621
